# C arrays of arrays: why do I need to cast TO const here?

Tags: c, arrays, constants

Why do I need to change the `print_args` call in this code to `print_args(argc, (const char**)argv)` to make it compile?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_args(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++ i) {
        puts(argv[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    print_args(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with gcc I get this error:

```
$ gcc -Werror -std=c99 -g const.c -o const
const.c: In function ‘main’:
const.c:10:2: error: passing argument 2 of ‘print_args’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
const.c:3:6: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

(Note that this is just a simplified example code to illustrate the problem.)

Comment: Tangential, good for you for using `-Werror`, but you should consider using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` too. They will probably give you some benign errors, but even those it would be good for you to understand.

Comment: `-Wextra` yes. `-pedantic` no, because I use GNU extension (guarded by `#ifdef __GNUC__`).

Comment: You can turn off individual types of warnings with extra `-Wno-foo` options. For the gnu extensions, I'm not sure what the particular option is, but perhaps something like `-Wno-gnu-extension`. You can even ignore warnings for particular lines or blocks with the right `#pragma`s. [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comp.lang.c FAQ [has a question on this](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html), summarizing:

> The reason that you cannot assign a `char **` value to a `const char **`
>   pointer is somewhat obscure. Given that the `const` qualifier exists at
>   all, the compiler would like to help you keep your promises not to
>   modify `const` values. That's why you can assign a `char *` to a `const
>   char *`, but not the other way around: it's clearly safe to "add"
>   `const`-ness to a simple pointer, but it would be dangerous to take it
>   away...In C, if you must assign or pass pointers which have qualifier
>   mismatches at other than the first level of indirection, you must use
>   explicit casts

Here's the example it gives, where line 3 should give a warning:

```
const char c = 'x';         /* 1 */
char *p1;                   /* 2 */
const char **p2 = &p1;      /* 3 */
*p2 = &c;                   /* 4 */
*p1 = 'X';                  /* 5 */
```

Lines 1 and 2 are obviously fine. On line 4, `&c` has type `pointer to const char`, and since `char **` is type `pointer to pointer to const char`, then `*p2` is also of type `pointer to const char`, so the statement is fine. Line 5 is also fine, because `p1` is type `pointer to char`, so you can modify what it points to.

So if line 3 is OK, then you end up doing exactly what you expect `const` to prevent you from doing, modifying the `char` pointed to by a `pointer to pointer to const char`, so line 3 is *not* allowed, and you can't assign `char **` to a `const char **` without a cast.

Note that putting the cast in merely hides the problem, it doesn't fix it. Line 3 above would work if you added the cast, and you'd be able to indirectly modify an apparently `const char`. While it's not always true, this is a good example of where succumbing to an apparent need to cast in C is often just a mistake.

Note that in C++, you could declare your function parameter `const char * const * argv` and it would work without a cast, and prevent the indirect modification.

Comment: Thanks. I have to re-read this in the morning (after I slept and when I can concentrate again).

Comment: `char * const *argv` works in plain C pretty well too. And doesn't require cast.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "works". It doesn't require a cast because it doesn't provide `const`ness for the `char`. `const char c = 'c'; const char * pc = &c; char * const * ppc = &pc;` wouldn't be allowed, and passing a `char **` to a function accepting `char * const * argv` would allow you to do `**argv = 'x';` and similar.

Comment: I'm confused. What is the associativity of the const modifier again? Because adding `typedef char* str;` and then using `void print_args(int argc, const str argv[])` works. What I want to say is that `print_args` won't change *anything* about the passed `argv`. `argv` shall be completely immutable within `print_args`.

Comment: Even declaring it as `void print_args(int argc, const str const*const argv)` works, but I think one of the `const`s is redundant. And can't I do the same without the `typedef`?

Comment: The rules are not all that simple to follow, largely you read from right-to-left, but as an example, `const ** char` is a (non-const) pointer to a (non-const) pointer to a `const char`. `const char * const * x` is a (non-const) pointer to a `const` pointer to a `const` char. `const char * const * const x` is a `const` pointer to a `const` pointer to a `const` char. `char ** const x` is `const` pointer to a (non-const) pointer to a (non-const) `char`.

Comment: To not change *anything* about `argv`, `const char * const * argv` is what you want. You can make `argv` point to something else, with this, but you cannot modify the thing to which it points. The only issue is that you can't convert a plain `char **` to this without a cast due to C's implicit pointer conversion rules. There is no theoretical reason why not - C just doesn't let you, while C++ does.

Comment: `typedef` is also not able to make this issue go away.